# php form image submit button - unable to submit

Tags: php, html

I am new to php. Though my doubt is very basic, but not understanding why my below form not able to submit? I am using actually image submit button.

Please tell me what wrong in below code:

```
<?php
    function test(){
    echo 'test';
    }

    var_dump($_POST['submit']); // here getting NULL, why?



    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       test();
    } 

?>
<form action="." method=post name="loginform">
<table>
       <tr>
        <input type="password" style="display:none" />
           <td width="130"><input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="255" ></td>
           <td width="136"><input type="image" src="button-log-in.gif" name="log in" alt=" log in" width="51" height="20" border="0"></td>
        </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no element which has 'submit' name. You're submitting two things,  indicated by the `name` attributes: "password" and "log in". `$_POST['...']` contains both of them.

If you'd like the function `test()` to be called upon submit, regardless of what is entered, you'd better add a hidden input field and check for its existence in PHP.

HTML:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="some_name">
...
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['some_name']))
{
   test();
}
```

Comment: so what should I change in my code inorder to happen submit?

Comment: @John And what would you like to get? The submit is already happening.

Comment: then why do iam getting NULL here: var_dump($_POST['submit']);

Comment: @John And tell me, what did you want to achieve with `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: what iam trying is:  I need to be able to call test() method as soon as I submit, but now its not happening. so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: @John You'd like to call test() regardless of what you enter in the form?

Comment: Now I understood you, but i have one small doubt why its becoming true for the condition: if(isset($_POST['uid']) && isset($_POST['password']))   , uid not there in above  code but there in my actual code.  I mean even though I didnt entered any values for uid and password, the above condition becoming true, any idea ?

Comment: @John And you want it not to be true if either or both of uid or password are empty?

Comment: @John Then just check `$_POST['uid']!=''&&$_POST['password']!=''`.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!  Have a great day :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114560/discussion-between-john-and-nicael).